# Why does this .toBlob() method of downloading a canvas require two clicks to work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to make an image on a canvas element ("canvas") downloadable.

I can't use right click > save as, as the actual canvas used is hidden. The user will only see a smaller representation of the full-size image on a separate canvas.

I was able to make this work using .toDataURL, but this failed when images/canvases became of a certain size. I am trying to combat this with .toBlob().

I have been able to get the below to work, but it initially takes two clicks to fire, and requires two clicks again every time the image is changed.

**Download Canvas as PNG**

```
var link = document.getElementById("download");

link.onclick = function() {

  link.download = "image.png";

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  },'image/png');
}
```

How can I eliminate the need to click twice each time I change the canvas image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toBlob()` is asynchronous (hence the function as parameter).
You have to wait until the function has finished its work before you can trigger the download.

```
var link = document.getElementById("download");
link.onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector("canvas").toBlob(function(blob){
    // here the conversion has finished
    // to trigger the download (again) we use a dummy link
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "image.png";
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.click();
  },'image/png');
};
```

Example

```js
var link = document.getElementById("download");
link.onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector("canvas").toBlob(function(blob) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "image.png";
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.click();
  }, 'image/png');
};

var change = document.getElementById("change");
change.onclick = function() {
  var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
};
change.onclick();

function getRandomColor() {
  return "rgb(" + (~~(Math.random() * 256)) + "," + (~~(Math.random() * 256)) + "," + (~~(Math.random() * 256)) + ")";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="download">Download</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="change">Change canvas</a>
<br />
<canvas width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>
```